# Azure Devops is not choosing private agent over hosted agent

Tags: azure-devops

I have setup a private agent with the following capabillities:  [image]

I have also selected the pool containing this agent as the default build agent for my React native build, building Android and iOS. The agent is running on my machine, that is capable of building both projects successfully. Both Android studio and xCode is installed.

However, when queuing a new build, Devops always chooses the Mac Hosted Agent.

The agent is running and displayed as online.

[image: Agent pool setting]

Comment: it means that it lacks some capabilities, i would say

Comment: Most likely, but where can I find the capabillities it needs and how can I add them. As I stated, the machine my agent is on can build both my Android and my iOS project. In my experience, that should be enough for the agent to build them as well.

Comment: i think somewhere in build properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose a specific pool, it's not going to randomly decide to try to build using a **different** pool. This means that you didn't set the pool correctly.

There are two places to set the pool:

- The top-level "Pipeline" section of the build definition
- The "Phase" level

Check both.

Comment: I have added a picture of where I set the pool, I cant seem to find anywhere else to set it, but I don't get the build editing GUI since the yml file is not in a Devops repository, its fetched from github. Can I set it in my yml file?

Comment: Found it in the yml file, I used a template as base, and it had the Mac image as default.